How to make a sphere from many small spheres
I'm trying to make this (picture found on internet):

So I added 2 spheres. One big and one small.
For the big one I added : Particules > Emitter > Render > object > I selected the small sphere
And it gives me this :

Do you know why ?
(I tried to add "Rigid body" to the small sphere but it didn't change anything)
Thank you very much !

You want to instance your small sphere to each vertex on the large sphere. See the Blender Manual entry on instancing or instance on Points in Geometry nodes.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149877/sphere-with-curved-faces-or-sphere-of-spheres

add an icosphere, add a geometry nodes modifier, add this node tree:

adapt the radius of the uvsphere to your needs.

